# How can I delete the row with invalid value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 16 invalid values in the dataset. How can I detect and delete rows with these invalid values?
Does it make more sense to mean or mode rather than delete the row of data?

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genceremre/Datasets/master/breast-cancer-wisconsin.csv"
names = ['Clump Thickness', 'Cell-Size', 'Cell-Shape', 'Marginal-Adhesion', 
         'Single Epithelial Cell Size', 
         'Bare Nuclei', 'Bland Chromatin',
         'Normal Nucleoli', 'Mitoses', 'Class']
dataset = read_csv(url, names = names)

print(dataset.shape)
print(dataset.head(10))

print(dataset.describe())

print(dataset.groupby('Class').size())

num_missing = (dataset[0:]=='?').sum()
print(num_missing)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a mix of strings and numeric values, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ['value 1', '1', -1, 0, 1, 2]})
df
Out[1]: 
       col
0  value 1
1        1
2       -1
3        0
4        1
5        2
```

If you do `df.info()`, then this will return:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6 entries, 0 to 5
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   col     6 non-null      object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 176.0+ bytes
```

As expected, this return an `object` data type since the column has a mix of strings and numeric values. To fix this, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
Out[2]: 
   col
0  NaN
1  1.0
2 -1.0
3  0.0
4  1.0
5  2.0
```

Notice that the string `value 1` returned `NaN`, because we passed `errors='coerce'`; however, the string `'1'` was changed to a numeric value of `1`.

Importantly, you can now filter the dataframe, because another `df.info()` shows that `pd.to_numeric` changed the `Dtype` to `float64`. The following line of code would have produced the error you mentioned, but now it will not, since the `Dtype` is `float64`:

```
df = df[df['col'] > 0]
```

Here is the full code:

```
In[3]:
        col
0   value 1
1   1
2   -1
3   0
4   1
5   2

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col' : ['value 1', '1', -1, 0, 1, 2]})
df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')
df = df[df['col'] > 0]
df

Out[3]: 
   col
1  1.0
4  1.0
5  2.0
```

You could also do:

```
df = df[df['col'].notnull()]
```

to return everything except the rows with `NaN` values rather than values > 0. It obviously depends on what you are trying to filter out. In your case the `?` would have been changed to `NaN` when doing `pd.to_numeric()` and passing `errors=coerce`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to remove all rows with 'Cell-Size' below zero.
This will do that:

```
dataset = dataset[dataset['Cell-Size'] > 0]
```

Comment: My problem is in the 'Bare Nuclei' column. I get the error '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: And what is the condition that you would like to remove rows by?

Comment: Following the solution you provided, I got the error string and int cannot be compared. 'Bare Nuclei' == '?' Is it possible to delete by selecting the containing line?

Comment: @genceremre you have strings in your columns. You need to clean that up before you can do a vectorized funciton on the whole column that returns `True` for all values  `>0`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to remove all rows containing a particular value:

`dataset = dataset[dataset.apply(lambda row: any(row != "?"), axis=1)]`